# trigger iframe's button from parent page MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

So, I have an iframe inside my application page (different domains) where the iframe has few fields and a hidden button that has a click event on there to do all the necessary stuffs (like the CRUD operation). The post is called via ajax, so there is not POST method on the iframe. The parent page has a button which is what should be used to when clicked, should trigger the click event inside the iframe. I did look into the postMessage and cross-origin and was able to find something that i have implemented on my solution. With that being added, when I click on the button on the parent page, nothing happens. I do not see any console error but nothing fires. This is what I have in my code.

```
<div id="main">
<iframe id="cardIframe" src="@($"https://localhost:44320/handlers?userId={Model.UserId}")"
        width="100%" height="300px" style="border: none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<hr class="mb-4" />
@Html.UI().Button("Continue to Checkout", size: UIElementSize.Block, uiClass: UIElementClass.Primary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "checkoutsubmit" })
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.checkoutsubmit').click(function (e) {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('cardIframe').contentWindow;
            window.iframe = iframe;
            iframe.postMessage("createvault", "*");
        });
    </script>
```

And in my iframe application (http://localhost:43402)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("click", clickEvent, false);

                function clickEvent(event) {
                    $('.processbraintree').trigger('click');
                }
                $('.processbraintree').click(function(e) { 
                    ..Do something
                });
                </script>
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong here. The fact that I do not see any error on the console doesn't help any. I have to have the iframe do the post of the form as it has all the braintree dropin ui stuffs. So, the parent has to be able to trigger the event inside of an iframe which currently does not happen right now.

Comment: You don't have an event listener for the `message` from `postMessage` in the iframe code. Would guess also that `iframe` is undefined due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: so in my iframe, do I need to add a listener for the postmessage..something like window.addEventListener("createvault", clickEvent, false);

Comment: Docs will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage. Look at exmples

Comment: So, I updated the listener on iframe to "message" instead of click. Now, the problem I run into is when I put the cursor on one of the iframe field, it triggers the button click event. I want to trigger it when I hit the button the parent page. It looks like the listener is working but not when I want to.